# Carousel View stop auto scroll when tap and hold - Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a carousal view in my Xamarin.Forms app. I used timer for auto scroll items of carousal view like this.

```
   StatusCarousal.ItemsSource = list;          
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7), (Func<bool>)(() =>
        {         
            StatusCarousal.Position = (StatusCarousal.Position + 1) % list.Count;
            return true;
        }));
```

It will auto scroll items in every 7 seconds. What I am trying to implement is when we hold the item of carousal the timer needs to stop. When we release it simply resume the timer and auto scroll to next item just like facebook or whatsapp status. How can I do that? Is there any property in carousal view which we can consume? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Effect to get the user touch status.And stop auto-scroll by defining a property .

The iOS, Android, and UWP all include a low-level API that allows applications to detect touch activity. These platforms all distinguish between three basic types of touch events:

- Pressed, when a finger touches the screen
- Moved, when a finger touching the screen moves

Released, when the finger is released from the screen

#### in Forms

```
public class TouchActionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TouchActionEventArgs(long id, TouchActionType type, Point location, bool isInContact)
    {
        Id = id;
        Type = type;
        Location = location;
        IsInContact = isInContact;
    }

    public long Id { private set; get; }

    public TouchActionType Type { private set; get; }

    public Point Location { private set; get; }

    public bool IsInContact { private set; get; }
}

public delegate void TouchActionEventHandler(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args);

public class TouchEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public event TouchActionEventHandler TouchAction;

    public TouchEffect() : base("Test.TouchEffect")
    {
    }

    public bool Capture { set; get; }

    public void OnTouchAction(Element element, TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
        TouchAction?.Invoke(element, args);
    }
}

public enum TouchActionType
{
    Entered,
    Pressed,
    Moved,
    Released,
    Exited,
    Cancelled
}
```

#### in Android

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Test")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(App29.Droid.TouchEffect), nameof(App29.Droid.TouchEffect))]

namespace App29.Droid
{
    public class TouchEffect:PlatformEffect
    {
        Android.Views.View view;
        Element formsElement;
        App29.TouchEffect libTouchEffect;
        bool capture;
        Func<double, double> fromPixels;
        int[] twoIntArray = new int[2];

        static Dictionary<Android.Views.View, TouchEffect> viewDictionary =
            new Dictionary<Android.Views.View, TouchEffect>();

        static Dictionary<int, TouchEffect> idToEffectDictionary =
            new Dictionary<int, TouchEffect>();

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            // Get the Android View corresponding to the Element that the effect is attached to
            view = Control == null ? Container : Control;

            // Get access to the TouchEffect class in the .NET Standard library
            App29.TouchEffect touchEffect =
                (App29.TouchEffect)Element.Effects.
                    FirstOrDefault(e => e is App29.TouchEffect);

            if (touchEffect != null && view != null)
            {
                viewDictionary.Add(view, this);

                formsElement = Element;

                libTouchEffect = touchEffect;

                // Save fromPixels function
                fromPixels = view.Context.FromPixels;

                // Set event handler on View
                view.Touch += OnTouch;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (viewDictionary.ContainsKey(view))
            {
                viewDictionary.Remove(view);
                view.Touch -= OnTouch;
            }
        }

        void OnTouch(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs args)
        {
            // Two object common to all the events
            Android.Views.View senderView = sender as Android.Views.View;
            MotionEvent motionEvent = args.Event;

            // Get the pointer index
            int pointerIndex = motionEvent.ActionIndex;

            // Get the id that identifies a finger over the course of its progress
            int id = motionEvent.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);


            senderView.GetLocationOnScreen(twoIntArray);
            Point screenPointerCoords = new Point(twoIntArray[0] + motionEvent.GetX(pointerIndex),
                                                  twoIntArray[1] + motionEvent.GetY(pointerIndex));


            // Use ActionMasked here rather than Action to reduce the number of possibilities
            switch (args.Event.ActionMasked)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                case MotionEventActions.PointerDown:
                    FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Pressed, screenPointerCoords, true);

                    idToEffectDictionary.Add(id, this);

                    capture = libTouchEffect.Capture;
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    // Multiple Move events are bundled, so handle them in a loop
                    for (pointerIndex = 0; pointerIndex < motionEvent.PointerCount; pointerIndex++)
                    {
                        id = motionEvent.GetPointerId(pointerIndex);

                        if (capture)
                        {
                            senderView.GetLocationOnScreen(twoIntArray);

                            screenPointerCoords = new Point(twoIntArray[0] + motionEvent.GetX(pointerIndex),
                                                            twoIntArray[1] + motionEvent.GetY(pointerIndex));

                            FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Moved, screenPointerCoords, true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CheckForBoundaryHop(id, screenPointerCoords);

                            if (idToEffectDictionary[id] != null)
                            {
                                FireEvent(idToEffectDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Moved, screenPointerCoords, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Pointer1Up:
                    if (capture)
                    {
                        FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Released, screenPointerCoords, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckForBoundaryHop(id, screenPointerCoords);

                        if (idToEffectDictionary[id] != null)
                        {
                            FireEvent(idToEffectDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Released, screenPointerCoords, false);
                        }
                    }
                    idToEffectDictionary.Remove(id);
                    break;

                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    if (capture)
                    {
                        FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Cancelled, screenPointerCoords, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (idToEffectDictionary[id] != null)
                        {
                            FireEvent(idToEffectDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Cancelled, screenPointerCoords, false);
                        }
                    }
                    idToEffectDictionary.Remove(id);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void CheckForBoundaryHop(int id, Point pointerLocation)
        {
            TouchEffect touchEffectHit = null;

            foreach (Android.Views.View view in viewDictionary.Keys)
            {
                // Get the view rectangle
                try
                {
                    view.GetLocationOnScreen(twoIntArray);
                }
                catch // System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Rectangle viewRect = new Rectangle(twoIntArray[0], twoIntArray[1], view.Width, view.Height);

                if (viewRect.Contains(pointerLocation))
                {
                    touchEffectHit = viewDictionary[view];
                }
            }

            if (touchEffectHit != idToEffectDictionary[id])
            {
                if (idToEffectDictionary[id] != null)
                {
                    FireEvent(idToEffectDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Exited, pointerLocation, true);
                }
                if (touchEffectHit != null)
                {
                    FireEvent(touchEffectHit, id, TouchActionType.Entered, pointerLocation, true);
                }
                idToEffectDictionary[id] = touchEffectHit;
            }
        }

        void FireEvent(TouchEffect touchEffect, int id, TouchActionType actionType, Point pointerLocation, bool isInContact)
        {
            // Get the method to call for firing events
            Action<Element, TouchActionEventArgs> onTouchAction = touchEffect.libTouchEffect.OnTouchAction;

            // Get the location of the pointer within the view
            touchEffect.view.GetLocationOnScreen(twoIntArray);
            double x = pointerLocation.X - twoIntArray[0];
            double y = pointerLocation.Y - twoIntArray[1];
            Point point = new Point(fromPixels(x), fromPixels(y));

            // Call the method
            onTouchAction(touchEffect.formsElement,
                new TouchActionEventArgs(id, actionType, point, isInContact));
        }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using UIKit;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Test")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(App29.iOS.TouchEffect), "TouchEffect")]

namespace TouchTracking.iOS
{
    public class TouchEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        UIView view;
        TouchRecognizer touchRecognizer;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            // Get the iOS UIView corresponding to the Element that the effect is attached to
            view = Control == null ? Container : Control;

            // Uncomment this line if the UIView does not have touch enabled by default
            //view.UserInteractionEnabled = true;

            // Get access to the TouchEffect class in the .NET Standard library
            App29.TouchEffect effect = (App29.TouchEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is App29.TouchEffect);

            if (effect != null && view != null)
            {
                // Create a TouchRecognizer for this UIView
                touchRecognizer = new TouchRecognizer(Element, view, effect); 
                view.AddGestureRecognizer(touchRecognizer);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            if (touchRecognizer != null)
            {
                // Clean up the TouchRecognizer object
                touchRecognizer.Detach();

                // Remove the TouchRecognizer from the UIView
                view.RemoveGestureRecognizer(touchRecognizer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TouchRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
    {
        Element element;        // Forms element for firing events
        UIView view;            // iOS UIView 
        App29.TouchEffect touchEffect;
        bool capture;

        static Dictionary<UIView, TouchRecognizer> viewDictionary = 
            new Dictionary<UIView, TouchRecognizer>();

        static Dictionary<long, TouchRecognizer> idToTouchDictionary = 
            new Dictionary<long, TouchRecognizer>();

        public TouchRecognizer(Element element, UIView view, TouchTracking.TouchEffect touchEffect)
        {
            this.element = element;
            this.view = view;
            this.touchEffect = touchEffect;

            viewDictionary.Add(view, this);
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            viewDictionary.Remove(view);
        }

        // touches = touches of interest; evt = all touches of type UITouch
        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

            foreach (UITouch touch in touches.Cast<UITouch>())
            {
                long id = touch.Handle.ToInt64();
                FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Pressed, touch, true);

                if (!idToTouchDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    idToTouchDictionary.Add(id, this);
                }
            }

            // Save the setting of the Capture property
            capture = touchEffect.Capture;
        }

        public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);

            foreach (UITouch touch in touches.Cast<UITouch>())
            {
                long id = touch.Handle.ToInt64();

                if (capture)
                {
                    FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Moved, touch, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckForBoundaryHop(touch);

                    if (idToTouchDictionary[id] != null)
                    {
                        FireEvent(idToTouchDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Moved, touch, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

            foreach (UITouch touch in touches.Cast<UITouch>())
            {
                long id = touch.Handle.ToInt64();

                if (capture)
                {
                    FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Released, touch, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    CheckForBoundaryHop(touch);

                    if (idToTouchDictionary[id] != null)
                    {
                        FireEvent(idToTouchDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Released, touch, false);
                    }
                }
                idToTouchDictionary.Remove(id);
            }
        }

        public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);

            foreach (UITouch touch in touches.Cast<UITouch>())
            {
                long id = touch.Handle.ToInt64();

                if (capture)
                {
                    FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Cancelled, touch, false);
                }
                else if (idToTouchDictionary[id] != null)
                {
                    FireEvent(idToTouchDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Cancelled, touch, false);
                }
                idToTouchDictionary.Remove(id);
            }
        }

        void CheckForBoundaryHop(UITouch touch)
        {
            long id = touch.Handle.ToInt64();

            // TODO: Might require converting to a List for multiple hits
            TouchRecognizer recognizerHit = null;

            foreach (UIView view in viewDictionary.Keys)
            {
                CGPoint location = touch.LocationInView(view);

                if (new CGRect(new CGPoint(), view.Frame.Size).Contains(location))
                {
                    recognizerHit = viewDictionary[view];
                }
            }
            if (recognizerHit != idToTouchDictionary[id])
            {
                if (idToTouchDictionary[id] != null)
                {
                    FireEvent(idToTouchDictionary[id], id, TouchActionType.Exited, touch, true);
                }
                if (recognizerHit != null)
                {
                    FireEvent(recognizerHit, id, TouchActionType.Entered, touch, true);
                }
                idToTouchDictionary[id] = recognizerHit;
            }
        }

        void FireEvent(TouchRecognizer recognizer, long id, TouchActionType actionType, UITouch touch, bool isInContact)
        {
            // Convert touch location to Xamarin.Forms Point value
            CGPoint cgPoint = touch.LocationInView(recognizer.View);
            Point xfPoint = new Point(cgPoint.X, cgPoint.Y);

            // Get the method to call for firing events
            Action<Element, TouchActionEventArgs> onTouchAction = recognizer.touchEffect.OnTouchAction;

            // Call that method
            onTouchAction(recognizer.element,
                new TouchActionEventArgs(id, actionType, xfPoint, isInContact));
        }
    }
```

**Note :** Don't forget to replace the namespace App29 to your own namespace

Now in Forms you could use it like

#### in xaml

```
<CarouselView ...>
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout.Effects>

                            <local:TouchEffect TouchAction="TouchEffect_TouchAction"  />

                        </StackLayout.Effects>
                      //...content

                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

#### in Code Behind

```
 bool isscroll=false;
```

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7), (Func<bool>)(() =>
            {
                if(isscroll)
                {

                }

                else
                {
                    carousel.Position = (carousel.Position + 1) % list.Count;
                }
                return true;
            }));
```

```
 private void TouchEffect_TouchAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
       if(args.Type==TouchActionType.Pressed||args.Type == TouchActionType.Moved)
        {
            isscroll = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isscroll = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks lucas..Let me try your solution

Comment: It been defined in class TouchEffect  in forms .

Comment: Ok thanks. Is "TouchEffect " is seperate class in forms?

Comment: Hi Lucas, your code worked. But facing one issue. If we hold the item and swiped to previous item then getting exceptions saying "System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 0'"  at  android render  " FireEvent(this, id, TouchActionType.Pressed, screenPointerCoords, true);

                    idToEffectDictionary.Add(id, this);

                    capture = libTouchEffect.Capture;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223393/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-anand).